# Lost data by my second viewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I got app with 2 view controllers, I'm typing values via NSStrings in Label and TextField in my first view controller and when I by pushing my navigation button go to my second view controller. When I return to my first view controller, I got entered early values. But when next after that I go to my second view controller - values entered via NSStrings in Label and TextField disappear. How to fix this that the values ​​saved? I tried to use strong and copy properties but that not helps me.
 I use segue and storyboards, segue with modal type, I use 1 navigation controller for first view controller. I got code only for modal type. First view controller is root for navigation

UPDATE
User entering values such as NSSting in first and in second VC. On navigation bar of first and in second VC there are bar buttons and with that user go throw VCs

type data in first VC -> go to second -> type data in second VC -> go to first(it saved data) -> go to second(it lost data)

I use that code to return to first VC from second:
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. Are you losing data in the first controller after coming back from the second? How are you coming back to the first controller from the second?

Comment: I update my post, please look at the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segues always instantiate new controllers, so when you go to the second controller for the second time, you're actually going to a new instance of that controller. If you want to go to the same instance, you can't use a segue. Instead you should make a property in your first controller that points to the second one, instantiate that second one, the first time you go to it, but not on any subsequent presentations (put in an if clause, and if the controller already exists, present it, if not, instantiate it first and then present it). The example below assumes that you have a custom controller of class SecondViewController, and that you've given it the identifier, "Second", in the storyboard.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondVC;

-(IBAction)presentSecondController:(UIButton *) sender {
    if (! self.secondVC) {
        self.secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
    }
    [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: thanks, But how need I work without segue now? I got a lot of any elements in my second VC, it will be impossible to initiate all this in class

Comment: @user3130451, it's no different if you present it manually, rather than doing a segue. Just don't connect a segue in the storyboard, and give the controller an identifier, so you can manually instantiate it. I've edited my answer to show you the code.

Comment: thanks, that works, but how can I set transition to flip horizontal? I tried      [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:1];

Comment: I got,     _secondVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;